# ng-repeat, filter and a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: angularjs

In my app I have 3 tables. Movies, users and movies_users. The Movie table has 2 colums, `title` and `movie_id`. My user table has 2 colums, `name` and `id`. And the movies_users table creates a relationship between them which results in a user can have many movies, and a movie can have many users. This works fine, but when I use a `"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies` I get all the movies added by all the users. But I only want to show the movies added by the current user.

So I'm looking for a method to connect Angular with the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between movies and users.

Comment: just lookup movies by user, and bind the movies array to scope.

Comment: I don't know how to lookup movies by user, that's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution proposal:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter: userHasMovie">{{movie.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular
.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.movies = [
        { movie_id: 1, title: 'a' },
        { movie_id: 2, title: 'b' },
        { movie_id: 3, title: 'c' }
    ];

    $scope.users = [
        { id: 1, name: 'd' },
        { id: 2, name: 'e' }
    ];

    $scope.movies_users = [
        { movie_id: 1, user_id: 1 },
        { movie_id: 2, user_id: 2 },
        { movie_id: 3, user_id: 1 },
        { movie_id: 3, user_id: 2 }
    ];

    $scope.currentUser = $scope.users[0];

    $scope.userHasMovie = function (val, ndx, arr) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.movies_users.length; i += 1) {
            if ($scope.movies_users[i].movie_id === val.movie_id &&
                $scope.movies_users[i].user_id === $scope.currentUser.id) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}]);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/xageyfdv/

Answer (score 0):

check out angular's filters:

`ng-repeat = "movie in movies | filter:{userId:userIdYouWantToFilterFor}"`

it works pretty much like the linux pipes. 
`filter:{userId:userIdYouWantToFilterFor}` returns a subset of `movies` containing all objects with the property `userId` matching `userIdYouWantToFilterFor`

Comment: I had something like that, but the movie table doesn't store the users id because I'm using a habtm relationship.